# Custom snapshots with stack 1.5.1

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I upgraded to `stack-1.5.1` from `stack-1.4.0`, and suddenly it started to refuse my `stack.yaml` with custom snapshot. Here's the beginning of the `stack.yaml`:

```
resolver:
  name: integer-simple-snapshot
  location: deps/flaw/integer-simple-snapshot.yaml

...
```

So it uses custom snapshot file located in the subdirectory, which contains the following resolver:

```
resolver: lts-9.0
```

Now stack prints the following when I try to build anything:

```
Could not parse '<path to project>/stack.yaml':
Aeson exception:
Error in $.resolver: failed to parse field 'resolver': expected ResolverWith (), encountered Object
See http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/
```

I tried to use non-object resolver, like `resolver: "deps/flaw/integer-simple-snapshot.yaml"` and other object and non-object variants, but all I can get is various cryptic errors about wrong formats.

I don't see anything changed about resolver's format at http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/, and the page https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/custom_snapshot/ still contains an example with custom snapshot. I also looked through a changelog and did not find anything related to snapshots or resolver format.

The project was perfectly buildable with these files before stack upgrade. What has changed? How can I use custom snapshot now?

I use Arch Linux and stack-1.5.1 from standard `stack` package if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extensible snapshots stuff has been a bit of an experimental feature, but I think it is stabilizing.  See this blog post on the changes - https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/07/stacks-new-extensible-snapshots

EDIT: Actually, the changes in that blogpost have not yet been released.  Is it possible that arch is shipping master version of stack??  That would be interesting.. What does "stack --version" say?

While not mentioned explicitly, I think it dropped using an object for the resolver, as the "name" field wasn't very useful.  So now it is just

`resolver: deps/flaw/integer-simple-snapshot.yaml`

In the future, we should probably try to require "require-stack-version: ..." in configs when they rely on new features.  To make things clearer to users, it may be helpful to add

`require-stack-version: ">= 1.5"`

to your config

Comment: As I noted in the question, I tried non-object version of `resolver` field and it doesn't work.

Comment: The full output of `stack --version`: https://gist.github.com/quyse/6d752ee482a9749b58d784416a4ebb78. I'm not sure how stack is built in Arch packages, I'll try with stack built from sources (tag v1.5.1).

Comment: Well, I downloaded official Linux_x64 static binary of `stack`, it reports the same version 1.5.1, and has the very same problem with my `stack.yaml`.

Comment: Ok, you're right, Arch package `stack` is built from master, not v1.5.1 tag, see commit in https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/stack . It's confusing that it reports the same 1.5.1 version, being different from official binary from haskellstack.org (which still works with previous format of custom snapshots). I guess it's Arch's issue than. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Hmm, looks like they are disabling the git version info from their build as well, shouldn't do that for a release build...  I've opened https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/55748 and https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3455 about this